# Probability of binomial distribution with dependent events

Tags: probability, lotteries

Problem: I played lottery and I bought $5000$ numbers of $100.000$. In the raffle, there are $2000$ prizes (or $2000$ tests), in that $2000$ prizes, $5$ are high prizes.

Question: What's my probability of get one high prize?

I used binomial with $5$ tests and $1$ success with probability of success $5%$. The problem of this approach is when you get a prize, the probability of success changes $(5000/99999)$

How to solve this? Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "I bought 5000 numbers of 100.000"?

Comment: @Remy I eddited the post. 5000 means I have the 5% of total numbers

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking along the path of $5000 \cdot\frac{1}{20000} \cdot(\frac{99995}{100000})^{4999}$. This yields an answer of approximately $19.47$ percent.

Answer (score 0):

The lottery is not described explicitly, so I’ll model its relevant part by assuming that each fifths of $N=100.000$ has an equal probability $p=1/{N\choose 5}$ be chosen as high prizes. Then the probability that no number of a fifth is among $n=5000$  bought numbers is ${N-n\choose 5}p\approx 0.774$, so your probability to get at least one high prize is about $0.226$.

Answer (score 0):

Using the binomial distribution for this problem is a very good approximation since the success probability is nearly the same for each of the 5 trials:
$$p(n=1|N=5,p=0.05) \approx 0.203627$$
If you want to work this out exactly, add the probabilities of the mutually exclusive situations in which you win exactly once, namely, you win only the first draw $(p_1)$, or only the second draw $(p_2)$, or the third...
$$p_1=\left({5000\over100000}\right)\left(1-{4999\over99999}\right)\left(1-{4999\over99998}\right)\left(1-{4999\over99997}\right)\left(1-{4999\over99996}\right)$$
$$p_2=\left(1-{5000\over100000}\right)\left({5000\over99999}\right)\left(1-{4999\over99998}\right)\left(1-{4999\over99997}\right)\left(1-{4999\over99996}\right)$$
You can see that each $p_i$ is the same, so
$$p = 5p_1 \approx 0.203634$$
which is very close to the binomial approximation.

Comment: Ok, but... Why is not the number of tests in the formula? In the lottery there are 2 thousand prizes, in which 5 are high prizes. So, why?

Comment: @Serginho We are **only** looking at the high prizes, so we don't use the fact that there is a total of 2000 prizes (even if there were 10 or 5 prizes, we would still only care about the 5 high prizes).